# Compare folders sizes and move to another folder

Tags: powershell, compare

I have this script that searches for files of the same size and if it is of the same size I let one where it is ("C:\folder1") and move the others copies to the "C:\files_compared".

```
$allfiles = Get-ChildItem -file -recurse "C:\folder1"  | Group-Object -Property length
foreach($filegroup in $allfiles)
{
    if ($filegroup.Count -ne 1)
    {
        $fileGroup.Group[1..($fileGroup.Count-1)] | move -Destination 'C:\Files_compared'
    }
}
```

The problem now is that I want to do this but only with folders, not files anymore.

I tried to put the -Directory instead of file but I don't know what to do next.

```
$allfiles = Get-ChildItem -Directory -recurse "C:\folder1"  | Group-Object -Property length
foreach($filegroup in $allfiles)
{
    if ($filegroup.Count -ne 1)
    {
        $fileGroup.Group[1..($fileGroup.Count-1)] | move -Destination 'C:\Files_compared'
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't compare file sizes: compare file hashes.  `(Get-FileHash -Path $Path).Hash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this, It compares a files in a folder and it moves to destinations folder if file length is same.

```
Get-ChildItem -file "E:\folder" | Group-Object -Property length | ForEach-Object {$_.Group | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Move-Item -Destination "E:\folder\move"}
```

Comment: I appreciate it. As a general tip: consider spreading long pipelines across multiple lines for readability, which is directly supported (without needing end-of-line escape char. `\``) if you break the line after each pipe symbol (`|`).